# Spinner control

Tags: wpf, controls

Does anyone know of a spinner control like the one we often see in android/iphone apps. something like this:[image: spinner]

It doesn't have to be free.

Comment: Are you creating a touch-screen application? If not, *please* don't use a control like this, no matter how "cool" you think it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SpinDotters at http://spindotters.codeplex.com/

There's source and a demo for WPF, SL, and Phone7.

You'd need to customize it a bit to get exactly what you want, but it could be a good starting point. e.g. you could combine several of the NumericUpDown controls...which "spin".

[image]